# Can't run file on boot-up with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried multiple ways (crontab and rc.local) of going about this. I have triple checked my code and processes each time but to no avail.

I am making a father's day gift with a button that says his favorite word, "No!".
Every time I reboot, my program does not respond at all to the GPIO and the button attached.
Is it how I have things structured in my sloppy code?

I'm not native in Python so I beg of you to help me.

When ran from the terminal or through Thonny, it runs perfectly. But no matter what, doesn't boot at start-up!

[Here is my rc.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxNeN.png)

Here's my code for the program:

```
import pygame
from random import randint
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


pygame.mixer.init()

#pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue


proverbFile = 'proverbs/Pro1.mp3'
num = 5
def randNo ():
    noFile = '/home/pi/Desktop/audio/no/No1.mp3'
    print('Executed!')
    default = 1
    global num
    pulled = 1
    while num == pulled:
        pulled = randint(1,4)
        print('Same!')

    num = pulled
    print(num)
    noFile = noFile.replace(str(default), str(num), 1)
    print(noFile)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(noFile)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    default = num

def button_callback(channel):
        print("Button was pushed!")
        randNo()

GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback)

#while True:
#    keyPress = input('Press q to quit: ')

#    if keyPress == 'q':
#        break;



#GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback) # Setup event on pin 10 rising edge
```

Comment: "Doesn't run on startup" and "doesn't run properly" are 2 different things. How about trying to redirect its stdout/stderr to a file you could later read? This is likely to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Anyway, if i had to guess... pygame installed for one user (pi), yet running at boot as another (root). Did you try "sudo sh" or something and then running your script from the root shell, just to test if it runs fine as root?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script to run when you boot into the LXDE environment, you could take a look at [this Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=11256):

```
Navigate to ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi
```

Open the autostart file in that folder:

```
$ sudo nano autostart
```

Add @midori on a new line. If you want to run something like a python script, put something like @python mypython.py on a new line. Running a script file would be @./superscript, but for some reason the script runs in an infinite loop (perhaps this will stop that).

```
Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter
```

Restart your Raspberry Pi into the LXDE environment.

answer from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)